# Linq - how to map (select) deconstructed tuples?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, tuples

I am trying to achieve a very simple thing. I have an Enumerable of tuples and I want to map and deconstruct them at the same time (as using `.Item1`, `.Item2` is ugly as hell).

Something like this:

```
        List<string> stringList = new List<string>() { "one", "two" };

        IEnumerable<(string, int)> tupleList =
            stringList.Select(str => (str, 23));

        // This works fine, but ugly as hell
        tupleList.Select(a => a.Item1 + a.Item2.ToString());

        // Doesn't work, as the whole tuple is in the `str`, and num is the index
        tupleList.Select((str, num) => ...);
        // Doesn't even compile
        tupleList.Select(((a, b), num) => ...);
```

Comment: `IEnumerable<(string str, int num)> ...` This works as a cast/new variable too, in case you don't control the creation of the original enumerable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1**

```
var result = tupleList.Select(x=> { var (str,num)=x; return $"{str}{num}";})
```

Output

```
one23 
two23
```

**Option 2**

If you are permitted to change the creation of tupleList, then you can do as following.

```
IEnumerable<(string str, int num)> tupleList = stringList.Select(str => (str, 23));
var result = tupleList.Select(x=>$"{x.str}{x.num}");
```

Option 2 eliminates the additional step required in Option 1.

Comment: This is close to what I want, but this has an additional step :(

Comment: @eddyP23: An "additional step" of *some* sort is unavoidable; tuple deconstruction cannot be combined with lambda declarations. There's an [open issue](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/125) for this which does not, however, specifically discuss declaration of lambda parameters, which may continue to be unsupported even if that issue is implemented.

Comment: I wished it could be done as elegantly as JavaScript/TypeScript.

Answer (score 5):

You can have named tuple members:

```
List<string> stringList = new List<string>() { "one", "two" };

// use named tuple members
IEnumerable<(string literal, int numeral)> tupleList =
    stringList.Select(str => (str, 23));

// now you have
tupleList.Select(a => a.literal + a.numeral.ToString());
// or
tupleList.Select(a => $"{a.literal}{a.numeral}");
```